# Number of subgroups of elementary abelian group not contained in one factor.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $B = A \times \langle x \rangle$ be elementary abelian of order $p^n$. Let $D$ be a subgroup of order $p^k$ with $k \le n-1$. Then we have 
$$
 m \cdot |A : D \cap A|
$$
different subgroups with $D \nleq A$, where $m$ denotes the number of subgroups of order $k-1$ in an elementary abelian subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$.
Suppose $D \nleq A$, then $|D \cap A| = p^{k-1}$ and $D = \langle D \cap A, ax \rangle$ with some appropriate $a \in A$. Then it dependes just on the coset of $a$ in $D\cap A$, and by choosing some $D \cap A$ and $a(D \cap A)$ the subgroup  $D$ is uniquely determined.

I see as $|D : A \cap D| \le |B : A| = p$ and $D \ne A \cap D$ we have $|A \cap D| = p^{k-1}$ and that $ax \notin D \cap A$, for otherwise we would have $x \in A$. Hence $|\langle D \cap A, ax \rangle| = p^k$. But why yield different cosets $a(D\cap A)$ different groups, and different groups correspond to different cosets? Why does $D\cap A$ and $a(D\cap A)$ determines the group $D$ uniquely?

Comment: This really very straightforward. Why don't you try to write down the proof? I'll start it off. Suppose that $E=D \cap A$ is fixed and, for $a \in A$, let $D_a = \langle E,ax \rangle$. Then $D_a = D_{a'} \Leftrightarrow ax \in D_{a'} \Leftrightarrow \ldots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing Derek's comment with $D_a = \langle E, ax \rangle$ and $E = D \cap A$ fixed:
\begin{align*}
 D_a = D_{a'} & \Leftrightarrow ax \in D_{a'} \\
              & \Leftrightarrow ax = a'x\cdot e \quad\mbox{with } e \in E \\
              & \Leftrightarrow ax(a'x)^{-1} \in E \\
              & \Leftrightarrow aa'^{-1} \in E \\
              & \Leftrightarrow aE = a'E.
\end{align*}
So we have a bijection between the subgroups $D_a$ and the cosets of $E$ in $A$.